# Windows 7 Public Documents Folder - how to move it to drive d:

Tags: windows-7, documents

I've just bought a new pc, and it is running Windows 7. I'm wanting to set up all of the documents folders such that they point to folders on a second drive partition (ie. disk D:) so that I have a nice separation of os from docs. I have managed to do this for each user on the machine (by opening up properties for documents folder and changing location). Hwoever, this procedure doesn't seem to work for the public documents folder. I cannot change the location for that one (even though I have administrator privileges). It is greyed out and cannot be changed.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just create a symlink or directory junction and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar question here that may help:

[Move the Public folders on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/16883/move-the-public-folders-on-windows-7)

It's odd that you cannot change the location for Public folders as you have for the others. I am able to change the location in the same way on my 7 Ultimate box. I wonder at the difference?

Are the permissions at the location you are trying to move to, sufficient?

Comment: This same issue occurred to me and i was able to change the location using the steps outlined in that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and edit the values in key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders

I would recommend backing up the key and a restart may be necessary.