# Delete Package Cache after uninstalling Visual Studio 2013 Express?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, cache, visual-studio

[Can I delete the folder C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\?](https://superuser.com/questions/455853/can-i-delete-the-the-folder-c-programdata-package-cache)

I have just found that I have 2Gb folder inside C:\ProgramData. According to the previous post it is connected to Visual Studio and it is not advisable to delete it.

I already completely uninstalled all of my Visual Studio, SQL, etc development tools by Microsoft and I am now cleaning up before I install Visual Studio Community.

Is it safe to assume that I can delete this folder now? C:\ProgramData\Package Cache? \I really need that space actually. My HDD is too small.\

Isn't there a tool that can safely clean up C:\ProgramData?

I am frustrated by how MS handles installation and deinstallation of the Visual Studio package - it cannot be done at once. Are there any tools to completely uninstall anything that comes with VS?

Comment: After I checked some more I assume that I maybe be safe to delete that folder but I am still not sure if it is related to VS only or to other packages as well.

Comment: The Package Cache is also used by other programs - but I also wonder why there's no tool to delete files from package cache after the software was uninstalled