# How to have one file in multiple directories with Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have some files that I need for multiple projects.
I need changes made to them to be applied in directories of each projects.
Copy pasting them all the time is unpractical and I could forget to do it sometimes. So I need a way around this.

Also is there a way to do this for folders as well?

Comment: This is what symbolic links ( NTFS junction points ) are used for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simbolic links. Open cmd (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type "cmd", enter) and navigate to the directory where do you want to have your files (use `cd` for that). Then type `mklink <link_name> <path_where_you_have_your_original_files>`.

You can do this for directories too, but add the switch `/D` in the above command.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed.  `mklink.exe` is your friend here.

It sounds like you want to create hard links for your files in all of your projects, so you would start with one of the files and create hard links to the other directories.  At this point, all of the file names will be pointing at the same chunk of data.  You could create symlinks as well, but I think a hard link fits your model better.

```
mklink /h linkname targetpath
```

You can also use it to create directory links, which will behave slightly differently as there will be one real directory, and the links will point to it.

```
mklink /d linkname targetpath
```

Further details at [What are the various link types in Windows? How do I create them?](https://superuser.com/questions/347930/what-are-the-various-link-types-in-windows-how-do-i-create-them)

Comment: This is odd, when I change either of the hard linked files and go to open the other I see that it's not updated. Why?

Comment: That doesn't seem possible . . . how odd.  Can you post the output of a DIR in both directories?

Comment: Well DIR command says they have different 'last modified' times, different size and the same name (they are in different directories)

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with it not being on c partition. Maybe something to do with the way I did it? (you can see my answer to this question of how exactly I did it)

Comment: well at least junctions work. Although Unity says it's asymbolic link, probably because the folders are on same partition.

Comment: @zoran404, Just tried this and it worked . . . did the file already exist in the second directory?  I did what you have in your answer and I see a hardlink.

Answer (score 0):

I up-voted your answers but I just want to add some tips I found for whoever visits this question:

First go to the folder where you want to create the link, then press `Shift + Right Mouse button` in the folder (this opens the extended menu) and select "Open command window here"

In command window type:

```
mklink /h newLinkName pathToOriginal
```

Similar goes for directories:

```
mklink /d newLinkName pathToOriginal
```

Btw instead of typing the path to the original file you can just drag and drop it into the console.