# Windows 10: One large partition from 2 physical hard drives

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I have 2 physical hard drives in my computer (SSD 32GB with alreaday installed Windows 10 + slow 7,2k RPM 512GB). Is there any way to make a one large system ('C:') partition out of theses 2 disks?

Comment: No; There isn't

Comment: Um... there can be, but it's too late now (you would have to reinstall Windows and everything else). And anyway, you shouldn't do that, for several good reasons. Instead create a _directory junction_. See http://superuser.com/questions/347930/what-are-the-various-link-types-in-windows-how-do-i-create-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any other partition that would be possible using the spanning partitions variety from dynamic disks. But since it is the system disk you boot from, it has certain limitations: it can only be a simple partition or a mirrored dynamic partition (as it must be accessible in its entirety at boot stage without all the fancy dynamic disk drivers available).