# Enabling the administrator account in windows 7

Tags: windows

Is there any way to enable a disabled administrator account on a computer with no administrator account currently enabled?

windows is 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to an elevated command prompt, read cmd.exe - then you should be able to.

## **Steps to activate administrator account from Windows:**

1. Login in to a Windows Account.
2. Press either the Windows key + R buttons simultaneously, or use the start menu and type out run.
3. Type in *cmd.exe*
4. In the shell, type out: *net user administrator /active yes*

This will enable the DEFAULT administrator account.

You may also change the password using *net user administrator * *

## **Steps to activate administrator account from Linux (complicated)**

1. You're going to have to download a Linux Distro, choose a small one from here: http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552
2. You're going to have to burn the Linux Distro to a USB/CD - This is called a Live USB. http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
3. Boot up from the Live USB and once you're in Linux navigate to your Windows directory:
4. Windows/System32 - Once you are in the System32 directory make a copy of cmd.exe and rename sethc.exe to sethc.exe.bak
5. Rename the copied cmd.exe file to sethc.exe
6. Switch off Linux, boot into Windows again and once you've reached the login screen, press the SHIFT key 5 times, a cmd windows should open. Proceed from previous instructions.

NOTE: For the first method, try typing out cmd in the start menu and running it as administrator before following the instructions.

Alternatively, look here for different methods: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/507-built-administrator-account-enable-disable.html

Comment: Access Denied !

Comment: Instead of using the run windows to open cmd, try typing cmd out in the start menu, right clicking and select "Run as Administrator" before following the steps.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try. but I had remote access to the computer. I finally have to GO to it.